Is ECCDH P-256 still secure in 2024?
I find it really easy to implement this algorithm in a browser and on my NodeJS server without any third-party dependencies.
After a little searching, I discovered that it seems outdated in 2024.
But is it still secure? As performance is not a priority for me.

This question is similar to: ECDH security vs. type of elliptic curve. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. So, it essentially has 128 bits of securiyt

TL;DR if "ECDH" refers to the non-ephemeral form, ECDH P-256 is not ideal and ECDHE P-256 is better (E meaning ephemeral)
ECDH P-256 is made up of two parts with different effects: the curve (P-256) and the method (ECDH).
First of all, the curve. P-256 is still considered secure as of 2024, as it provides 128 bits of security. With other algorithms (e.g. MD5 hashes), this is not enough. However, $2^{128}$ MD5 operations is much easier than $2^{128}$ operations on an elliptic curve.
The curve itself is the subject of some scrutiny, as it was standardized by a US government agency (NIST) and the NSA has been caught backdooring an elliptic-curve CSPRNG. It's almost certainly fine, as nobody's found anything yet, but you could also use Ed25519 if it's a problem.
Now, the method. "ECDH" could refer to the abstract concept of elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman, in which case this scheme is perfectly secure.
However, it could also specifically mean the non-ephemeral version (like how it is used in TLS), in which case there are some problems. The rest of the answer will assume the latter.
Non-ephemeral ECDH (as opposed to the ephemeral version) is not very secure, as it lacks forward secrecy. ECDH does not refresh the key used on the server side each time. Each client gets their own key, but if the server's private key is compromised, attackers can decrypt any conversation that used that specific key pair.
ECDHE solves this by using a different one each time. This means that even if one private key is compromised, all you can do is decrypt one session. This property of forward secrecy is the standard for modern cryptography.
